# On a theorem of Hardy

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification

Suppose $f$ is a twice-differentiable real function defined on $ [0, \infty) $ , $f’’$ is bounded, and $f$ vanishes at infinity. I’d like to show $f’$ also vanishes at infinity. I believe I have a proof.

Proof: We apply Taylor’s theorem on the interval $ (x,x+h)$ where $h>0$. We get $$ f’(x)= \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\frac{1}{2}hf’’(ξ)$$ for some number $ ξ $ depending possibly on $x$ and $h$. Taking limsups as $ x  \to \infty$ of both sides, using the fact that f vanishes at infinity, and $f’’$ is bounded gives $$ \limsup_{x \to \infty} f’(x) = Ch $$ for some constant C not depending on h. Taking $ h \to 0$ shows $\limsup_{x \to \infty} f’(x) = 0$. A similar argument shows that $\liminf_{x \to \infty} f’(x) = 0$, giving the result.

I’d appreciate if someone could check out this proof and see if they’re something I overlooked.

Comment: It seems OK to me... My only comment is that you could skip the "similar argument" if you made your TS equality into an inequality with absolute values... Agree?

Comment: @peterag Ah I see. Thank you very much.